# reject binary on iTunes connect issue, can not see remove button

Tags: app-store-connect

As you can see you in the picture, I want to reject my binary when waiting for review, but i can not see the blue rectangle which is shown in the official guide in my view.

Any one can help? Thanks!

Comment: No, I can't see a picture